Extraer ultimos datos y compararlos para la toma de decisiones
quisiera que me ayudaran con la siguiente macro sobre todo la primera que es la que yo le he adoptado que consiste en que si en la celda L1 es igual a Mezcla de la hoja Cemento del libro Cemento.xlsm traer el ultimo dato de la columna K(%P. Ígnea) y tiene por condición que debe ser igual a 4 del rango de la columna B (Molino) de la hoja Mezcla Adición del libro Base datos Cementos producido 2024.xlsx. Resulta que no me trae el dato correspondiente. En caso de que no diga mezcla ejecute la macro Caliza.
Ahora la macro Caliza hace lo siguiente, revisa la columna K(%P. Ignea) de la hoja Caliza Adición Cto del libro Prehomo.xlsx y compara los dos últimos datos, si el ultimo dato es mayor que el anterior realiza un promedio entre ellos, ahora si el ultimo dato es menor toma ese dato. Luego verifica el ultimo dato de la columna K(%P. Ígnea) y tiene por condición que debe ser igual a 4 del rango de la columna B (Molino) de la hoja Caliza Adición del libro Base datos Cementos producido 2024.xlsx, entonces si el valor obtenido es menor que el obtenido en la fase anterior toma este nuevo valor sino deja el valor anterior.
Espero me haya dado a entender
Adjunto la macro y los archivos
Archivos: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bIYk94qdW6Ow6NlpymSEn7YfgF8G-aZj/view?usp=drive_link
Si es posible mejorar esta macro se los agradecería.
Saludos
Claudio Rengifo
`Sub Mezcla()
Dim sw1 As Workbook
Dim sh1, sh6 As Worksheet
Dim ndatos, uvalor As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CEMENTO")

If sh1.Cells(1, "L").Value = "Mezcla" Then

Set sw = Workbooks.Open("\\10.7.10.1\calidad\RegCalidad 2024\Molienda de Cemento y Empaque\Base datos Cementos producido 2024.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
Set sh6 = Sheets("MEZCLA ADICION")

ndatos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(sh6.Range("K371:K736"))
uvalor = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh6.Range("K371:K736"), ndatos)
sh1.Cells(1, "N") = uvalor

sh6.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Else

Call Caliza

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Sub Caliza()
Dim jh1, jh3 As Workbook
Dim sh1, jh2, jh4, jh6 As Worksheet
Dim jFila, i, Filacal As Long
Dim Cal(0) As Double
Dim fecha As Date

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CEMENTO")

Set jh1 = Workbooks.Open("\\10.7.10.1\calidad\SEGUIMIENTO HORA-HORA\PREHOMO.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
Set jh2 = Sheets("CALIZA ADICIÓN CTO")

jh2.Activate
jh2.Cells(4, "A").Select
jFila = ActiveCell.Row

For i = 1 To 4

jFila = jh2.Cells(jFila, "A").End(xlDown).Row

Next i

jFila = Cells(jFila, "K").End(xlUp).Row

If jh2.Cells(jFila, "K") < jh2.Cells(jFila - 1, "K") Then

Cal1 = jh2.Cells(jFila, "K")

Else

Cal1 = (jh2.Cells(jFila, "K") + jh2.Cells(jFila - 1, "K")) / 2

End If

Set jh3 = Workbooks.Open("\\10.7.10.1\calidad\RegCalidad 2024\Molienda de Cemento y Empaque\Base datos Cementos producido 2024.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
Set jh4 = Sheets("CALIZA ADICION")
Set jh6 = Sheets("MEZCLA ADICION")

For i = 371 To 736

If (Not (jh4.Cells(i, "K") = Empty)) And jh4.Cells(i, "A") = (fecha - 1) And jh4.Cells(i, "B") = "4" Then

Cal2 = jh4.Cells(i, "K")

Else

If Cal2 < 2 Or Cal2 > 59 Then

Cal2 = 60

End If

End If

Next i

Filacal = jh4.Cells(736, "K").End(xlUp).Row
Cal3 = jh4.Cells(Filacal, "K")

If Cal2 = 60 Then

Cal4 = Cal3

Else

Cal4 = Cal2

End If


jh4.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close

If Cal1 < Cal4 Then

Caliza = Cal1

Else

Caliza = Cal4

End If

sh1.Activate
sh1.Cells(1, "N") = Caliza

jh2.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`


Y cual es el problema?

Buenos días y gracias por responder, el problema es que al ejecutar la macro Mezcla no me trae el ultimo valor correspondiente. Y si es posible mejorar la macro Caliza.

No sabemos que quiere decir mejorar la macro Caliza.. tarda mucho? ocupa mucho espacio? y tampoco podemos saber porque no trae el ultimo valor correspondiente, no hay forma de probar esto... que valor trae? que valor deberia traer?

Gracias por responder, amigo el ultimo dato que me debe arrojar de la columna K de la hoja Mezcla Adición del libro Base datos Cementos producido 2024.xlsx es 29.81 y me esta arrojando 28.05. La macro Caliza es muy lenta
